# Hive - Unable to create PARTITIONS in EXTERNAL TABLE STORED BY Hbase

Tags: external, hbase, hive

HBase table specs

```
DESCRIPTION ENABLED {NAME => 'hbase_2_hive_names', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'age',
DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => 
'3', COMPRESSION =>  true 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS 
=> 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true', BLOCKCACHE 
=> 'true'}, {NAME => 'id', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', 
REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 
'2147483647', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', 
ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'name', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING 
=>'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION => 
'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => 
'65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}]}
```

Create external table in Hive:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_hive_names(hbid INT, id INT,  fn STRING, ln STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (age INT) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,id:id,name:fn,name:ln,age:age")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_2_hive_names");
```

Get following error

```
 Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException:
   MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException      
   org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe: columns has 4 elements while hbase.columns.mapping has 5 elements (counting the key if implicit)
```

Answer (score 0):

List of HIVE columns (hbid INT, id INT,  fn STRING, ln STRING) = 4 columns you are trying map into 5 qualifiers "hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key, id:id, name:fn, name:ln, age:age"

be attentive ;)

Answer (score -2):

`Hbase` has row ,so you should add `key string` when you `create external table` like this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE
   hbase_hive_names(key STRING,hbid INT, id INT, fn STRING, ln STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (age INT) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
   ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,id:id,name:fn,name:ln,age:age")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_2_hive_names");
```

Comment: It's worked on my machine and can you tell me the error you meet when you test the answer?@slayton

Comment: Probably you already have partition = age. Try something like ALTER TABLE hbase_hive_names ADD PARTITION(age='22');